# Looking for fastest way to find values between thresholds in xarray of 3600x20x20

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to count the number of days where the average temperature is between two values (let's say 293K and 303K). This needs to be calculated for an approximately 10000x20x20 large array (time, lat, lon). At this size the efficiency of the code becomes a problem. I know for one that a loop is rather inefficient but I haven't been able to think of another way to code this.

So in brief, ***I'm looking for a more efficient piece of code*** than what I've inserted below. Any tips or references are welcome!

(In addition to the above, I'm quite new to python so any feedback you might have will be appreciated!)

First I had three nested loops (`for i` .. `for j`... `for k`..) but this took about 100 times longer. Using the `1*(boolean)` proves far more efficient. I'm now trying to get rid of my last loop (`for i`..). The speed is so important because this script will be included in an interactive web app.

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import time

# Firstly construct a data array of temperatures with dimensions latitude, longitude, time
da_t1 = xr.DataArray([[290, 295, 300, 305, 295],
                       [295, 295, 305, 295, 290],
                       [300, 300, 300, 305, 295],
                       [290, 295, 300, 305, 295],
                       [290, 295, 300, 305, 295]],
                  dims=['lat', 'lon'],
                  coords={'lat': [-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5], 'lon': [33, 35, 37, 39, 41]})

da_t2 = xr.DataArray([[295, 295, 305, 295, 295],
                       [295, 295, 305, 295, 290],
                       [300, 300, 300, 305, 295],
                       [290, 300, 300, 305, 305],
                       [290, 285, 285, 285, 295]],
                  dims=['lat', 'lon'],
                  coords={'lat': [-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5], 'lon': [33, 35, 37, 39, 41]})

da = xr.concat([da_t1, da_t2], 'time')


# Create an array of zeros to keep track of number of days within certain temperature range for each cell 
zeros = da[0]
zeros.values = np.zeros((da.sizes['lat'], da.sizes['lon']))


# Loop through the timesteps and the cells to count for each cell the number of days in the temperature range

trange = (293,303)


# Here's the part that could use faster performance

start = time.time()

for i in range(0, (len(da.time))):
    int_array = 1*(da.values[i] >= trange[0]) * (da.values[i] <= trange[1])
    zeros = zeros + int_array

end = time.time()

print('time elapsed: ',end-start)
print(zeros.values)
```

The result is an array that displays the number of days within the specified temperature range over the selected time period. In this case:

```py
zeros = 
[[1. 2. 1. 1. 2.]
 [2. 2. 0. 2. 0.]
 [2. 2. 2. 0. 2.]
 [0. 2. 2. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 2.]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be

```
((da >= trange[0]) & (da <= trange[1])).sum(axis=0)
```

result:

```
# <xarray.DataArray (lat: 5, lon: 5)>
# array([[1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
#        [2, 2, 0, 2, 0],
#        [2, 2, 2, 0, 2],
#        [0, 2, 2, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0, 2]])
# Coordinates:
#   * lat      (lat) float64 -5.0 -2.5 0.0 2.5 5.0
#   * lon      (lon) int32 33 35 37 39 41
```

---

EDIT: Timing measurements using `%timeit` in IPython console:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

da_big = xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(290, 305, (10000, 5, 5)),
              dims=['time', 'lat', 'lon'],
              coords={'lat': [-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5], 'lon': [33, 35, 37, 39, 41]})

def OP(darr, trange = (293,303)):
    zeros = darr[0]
    zeros.values = np.zeros((darr.sizes['lat'], darr.sizes['lon']))

    for i in range(0, (len(darr.time))):
        int_array = 1*(darr.values[i] >= trange[0]) * (darr.values[i] <= trange[1])
        zeros = zeros + int_array

    return zeros.values
def SumAxis(darr, trange = (293,303)):
    return ((darr >= trange[0]) & (darr <= trange[1])).sum(axis=0)

%timeit -n10 OP(da_big)
%timeit -n10 SumAxis(da_big)

# 466 ms ± 13.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 1.89 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Calculation time has been reduced with a factor 20, terrific!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that it helps. However, I'd still be interested in the actual numbers of your timing results, because I measured a factor 200. For a 10000x20x20 data Array your code needed about 450ms and the above mentioned solution about 2ms. See my edit for the results.

Comment: Supplemental: if you don't use `astype(int)` you're even a little more faster - it's not needed here, obviously the conversion is done while summing up on the fly. Of course this is not for additional factors but about 25%... See my edit; timing will follow soon.

Comment: Using the code that you used I get similar results: for the loop 297 ms ± 6.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each), and for the sum
1.68 ms ± 26.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each). I probably misread a 0 earlier on. Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just use element-wise boolean / logical indexing, like

```
in_between = np.logical_and(da.values[i] >= trange[0], da.values[i] <= trange[1])

sum_in_between = np.count_nonzero(in_between) # True = 1, False = 0
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm looking for something like this, but then with the sum for each index. `sum_in_between` returns the number of days within the range for all cells/elements combined.

Comment: Please look at the axis-keyword of np.count_zero, also at np.bincount, np.where, np.digitize. One of them should fit your needs.

Comment: I'm looking into it. However this solution has also still got the `for i ..` loop. Do you think that's inevitable?